# Metro8 SqlConnection

Tags: microsoft-metro, sqlconnection

Is there any way to use `SqlConnection` in Metro 8? (In forms it was like `SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...)`)
How to connect with database created in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: i found this -http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134047/how-might-a-windows-8-metro-app-handle-back-end-database-access



  [1]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134047/how-might-a-windows-8-metro-app-handle-back-end-database-access

Answer (score 1):

You can't use System.Data in Metro apps.  The only way that I've seen to get around this is to create a non-WinRt service that does communicate with the DB and talk to that.  Alternatively, don't use Metro.

Answer (score -1):

Have you referenced the proper DLL with "using System.Data.SqlClient;"? There/Then you can find the needed class SqlConnection.

Also you can try SqlHelper.cs to write less code and easily connect to a sqldb. [SQL HELPER](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidD4121D6E4BCA2DAB656D770903FECBFF7427D242.aspx)

Comment: There's no way to add "using System.Data" in Metro Style Application in Visual Studio 2012... :(

Comment: I got that error :

Error 2 The base class or interface 'System.ComponentModel.Component' in assembly 'System, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could not be resolved c:\System.Data.dll

after I added System.Data dll file.